# SwiftUI Query Realm Database

Tags: swift, database, realm

In my Realm DB for ChatMessage I have the following data object:

When i follow the tutorial on retrieving data/query : https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/crud/read/

[image]

```
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let specificPerson = realm.object(ofType: ChatMessage.self, 
forPrimaryKey:  ObjectId("6369ee9db15ac444f96eb5d6"))
        print(specificPerson!.author as String)
```

I receive fatal error Nil, it cannot find anything. from the line

```
        print(specificPerson!.author as String)
```

`LiveChat/ChatView.swift:59: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

When I do a broader query for all,

```
    let chatM = realm.objects(ChatMessage.self)
    print(chatM)
    print(type(of: chatM))
```

I receive empty object

```
Results<ChatMessage> <0x7fe4d163efa0> (

)
Results<ChatMessage>
```

I am adding the Chat messages Via

```
    @ObservedResults(ChatMessage.self, 
sortDescriptor: SortDescriptor(keyPath: "timeStamp", ascending: true)) var messages


    private func addMessage(){
    let message = ChatMessage(room: room, author: userName, text: messageText)
    $messages.append(message)
    messageText = ""
}
```

Similar to https://github.com/mongodb-developer/LiveTutorialChat/blob/main/iOS/LiveChat/LiveChat/Views/ChatsView.swift

Comment: What line is throwing the error?

Comment: print(specificPerson!.author as String)
throws an error because it received no data.  
Also, when I print     let chatM = realm.objects(ChatMessage.self)
    print(chatM) it shows an empty object

Comment: Edit your question to include the line that is crashing. Note that you should avoid the `!` force-unwrap operator. I call that the "crash if nil" operator, because that's what it does.

Comment: edited. Why is it nil though?  The picture I attached show that it exist in the database.

Comment: I haven't used Realm, so I'm at a disadvantage here. What does "database deleted" mean? Based on what you get when you ask for ALL records, it looks like the DB doesn't contain any ChatMessage objects, which would explain why you're getting a nil.

Comment: What do you mean database deleted? Yea, i am not sure why I am not getting anything back.

Comment: Could it be related to needing to make call asynchronous? not getting db back in time?

Comment: The first issue; the query is for an Objectid ending in `96eb5d6` and what shown in your database screenshot ends in `fabecd5` so that object doesn't exist. Secondly the screenshot shows "Database Deleted" so - perhaps there is no data? Can you update and clarify the question with your actual data? Lastly it's not clear what this `$messages.append(message)` is supposed to do because `$messages` is not defined in the question. Please review the following guide on asking questions: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ```$messages``` is defined ```@ObservedResults(ChatMessage.self, 
sortDescriptor: SortDescriptor(keyPath: "timeStamp", ascending: true)) var messages``` The database deleted is a bad screenshot. i was trying to query multiple IDs but i must of not updated the screenshot to the correct objectID when I pasted the code.  From what Cheezzhead said below. I must be opening realm incorrectly.  I am not entirely sure how to properly open realm to directly access the database online

Comment: If the question contains erroneous information and incomplete or missing code, it will lead us down the wrong path and make answers inaccurate. Please read the link about on how to create a proper question and update yours with more info so we can help. Right now, it's a total guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your updated code:

So yes, you are indeed creating the objects (using the `.append(_:)` method on an `@ObservedResults` collection) in a correct way. This means that you are likely opening the wrong realm database when you're querying for the objects. Please have a look at [Realm's documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/swiftui/configure-and-open-realm/) regarding realm configuration, specifically on how to set the [default configuration](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/realm-files/configure-and-open-a-realm/#std-label-ios-default-and-file-url-realm). Calling `try! Realm()` without any parameters will use this default configuration to open the database.

##### Original reply

If `let chatM = realm.objects(ChatMessage.self)` returns an empty `Results` object, the realm you're querying does not contain any objects of the `ChatMessage` type. It's as simple as that. Logically, `let specificPerson = realm.object(ofType: ChatMessage.self,  forPrimaryKey:  ObjectId("6369ee9db15ac444f96eb5d6"))` would then also return nil.

Without seeing how and where you're creating the missing `ChatMessage` objects, it's hard to say what's going wrong. Some common missteps:

- **You are querying the wrong realm database**: If you are only every accessing realm through `let realm = try! Realm()` this shouldn't be a problem.
- **You haven't actually added any `ChatMessage` object to the realm database**: Simply initializing an object is not enough, You need to explicitly add objects to the Realm database using either `Realm.create()` or `Realm.add()`:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let exampleObject = ChatMessage()
print(realm.objects(ChatMessage.self).count) // Prints "0"

// Add to the realm using either create() or add()
realm.add(exampleObject)

print(realm.objects(ChatMessage.self).count) // Prints "1"
```

Comment: Ah, could it be i am accessing the local Realm Database? when in fact the DB  I want is the one online?  I updated how I add the chatMessages to the original question

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so try! Realm() is opening the wrong database.  Got it.  This official MongoDB Github tutorial [github](https://github.com/mongodb-developer/RTicket/blob/6a1d2878dcb50cec4d8ace88106714b91050c2e2/iOS/RTicket/RTicket/Model/Ticket.swift#L38) uses let realm = try Realm() to open the database that is stored on the offical atlas mongodb, curious why it works for them

Comment: Well, that's a bit of a unique case because the two functions that use `try Realm()` are both for use in XCode's Preview device (specifically [here](https://github.com/mongodb-developer/RTicket/blob/6a1d2878dcb50cec4d8ace88106714b91050c2e2/iOS/RTicket/RTicket/Views/TicketsView.swift#L95)). Not sure how the tutorial covers this but I would stick to the official documentation that I linked as a working example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I gather I must use ```// Open the realm with a specific file URL, for example a username
let username = "GordonCole"
var config = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration
config.fileURL!.deleteLastPathComponent()
config.fileURL!.appendPathComponent(username)
config.fileURL!.appendPathExtension("realm")
let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)
```

Comment: Not entirely sure, how would i know the fileURL. is it located somewhere on my db on https://cloud.mongodb.com/ ?

Comment: Also what allows me to even receive the data from the atlas, how does @ObservedResults(ChatMessage.self,  sortDescriptor: SortDescriptor(keyPath: "timeStamp", ascending: true)) even get the data without opening realm?

Comment: `@ObservedResults` opens the realm implicitly using the default configuration, as explained in the [Realm docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/swiftui/configure-and-open-realm/) (it's literally the first thing the page explains). How and where to open a Synced Realm is beyond the scope of this question as we would need to see more of your code. I would suggest reading that documentation page thoroughly, and opening a new question if you still can't figure it out. Good luck! (and don't forget to mark this question as solved)